# Выборка по динамическим классам

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Код работает. Делает выборку по классу и выводит результат в консоль.

Представленная страничка с кодом статическая. Если я формирую блок `#tabs_zakaz` со всем содержимым динамически, используя `jqueri ui tabs`, то выборка по классу не работает, в консоли нет сообщений об ошибках. При этом `firebug`  видит класс, по которому выбираю

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем здесь дело. Эта проблема взорвала мне мозг.

Пробовал даже

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Хотя он там не нужен

Comment: Думаю, что я не один, кто подустал от таких вопросов. Читаем [первоисточник](http://api.jquery.com/on/) или [на русском](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)

Comment: простите, не понял я. по вашей ссылке информация о событиях и всплывании. в моей проблеме ничего подобного нет

вот кстати ссылка на мой статический код http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/sele/ для первого поста

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, Что ж вы не поняли? В вопросе было сказано, "*Если я формирую блок #tabs_zakaz со всем содержимым динамически*", это значит, что этому предшествует какое-то событие. В этом случе, обработка динамически созданных/измененных объектов, делается с использованием метода .on() и/или делегированной обработки событий.

P.S. И при чем там ссылка, которую вы дали выше - уже не понял я ))

Comment: а можно для особо тупых разжевать? допустим здесь http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/sele/ блок #tabs_zakaz сформирован динамически(хотя он там статический). как бы мне сделать выборку $('#tabs_zakaz .ui-state-active a')

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> а можно для особо тупых разжевать?

Для того, чтоб не приходилось разжевывать, советую в вопросе указывать задачу в полном объеме, а не абстрактно. В противном случае, приходится перечислять все возможные варианты, в попытке найти тот, который окажется ближе к вашей проблеме.

Предположим, что у нас есть статический блок с **id="static_block"**. В него мы динамически добавляем еще какой-то блок(и) с классом **".dinamic_block"**. Теперь, вам нужно сделать выборку по классу этого динамического блока. И тут у меня бы возник вопрос: "В связи с чем?". Если эта выборка делается в связи с каким-либо событием пользователя, то, как я уже писал, есть метод .on() и [вот как это будет выглядеть](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/EdAN8/). Если же необходимо делать выборку без события пользователя, то [эти действия проводятся сразу](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/EdAN8/1/) после добавления такого динамического объекта. Это же правило одинаково действует и [при добавлении после ajax-запроса](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/EdAN8/2/).